# how to show a text when hovering over an image in html and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have written this code to display 4 images in the left of the page and when hovering over an image it appears bigger at a div to the right of those images ..
i want some text to show up under the big image at the right, but i can't do it.
Any suggestions?
Here is my code:

```css
body{padding:20px 100px}

a img{display:block;border:none;}

.image-holder{
 float:right;
 margin:42px 560px 0px 0;
 width:300px;
 height:350px;
 background:#ffffff;
 border:10px solid #000;
 padding:3px;
 position:relative;
 z-index:1;
}
ul.links{
 list-style:none;
 margin:0 0px;
 padding:0;
 border:5px solid #000;
 border-bottom:none;
 width:100px;
 
}
.links li{
 width:100px;
 border-bottom:10px solid #000; 
}

.links li a span{
 position:absolute;
 right:682px;
 top:222em;
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 z-index:2;
}
.links li a:hover{
 background:teal;
 color:#0f0;
 
}
.links li a:hover span {top:200px;

}
 
h1{text-align:center;margin:1em 0;}
```

```html
 
 <p class="image-holder"></p> 
 <ul class="links"> 
  <li><a href="image1.jpg"><img src="image1.jpg" width=100 height=100><span><img src="image1.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="example image" /></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="image2.jpg"><img src="image2.jpg" width=100 height=100><span><img src="image2.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="example image" /></span></a></li> 
  <li><a href="image3.jpg"><img src="image3.jpg" width=100 height=100><span><img src="image3.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="example image" /></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="image4.jpg"><img src="image4.jpg" width=100 height=100><span><img src="image4.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="example image" /></span></a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Which text are you trying to show and where in the code are you trying to do it?

Answer (score 2):

```css
body{padding:20px 100px}

a img{display:block;border:none;}

.image-holder{
 float:right;
 margin:42px 560px 0px 0;
 width:300px;
 height:350px;
 background:#ffffff;
 border:10px solid #000;
 padding:3px;
 position:relative;
 z-index:1;
}
ul.links{
 list-style:none;
 margin:0 0px;
 padding:0;
 border:5px solid #000;
 border-bottom:none;
 width:100px;
 
}
.links li{
 width:100px;
 border-bottom:10px solid #000; 
}

.links li a span{
 position:absolute;
 right:682px;
 top:222em;
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 z-index:2;
        text-align:center;
}
.links li a:hover{
 background:teal;
 color:#0f0;
 
}
.links li a:hover span {top:200px;

}
 
h1{text-align:center;margin:1em 0;}
```

```html
 
 <p class="image-holder"></p> 
 <ul class="links"> 
  <li><a href="image1.jpg"><img src="image1.jpg" width=100 height=100><span><img src="image1.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="example image" /><em>Some Text</em></span></a></li>
 </ul>
```

Simply add a tag in span after `<img>` tag as i used in above code and if you want to align it to center then add `text-align:center;` property to span css as i used above.

Comment: Open snippet on full page for exact result :)

Answer (score 2):

A very simple way to do it is to add the `title` attribute inside of your `<img>` tag, like this:

```
<img title="Your text"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using javascript if that is valid:

```
<li onmouseover="onMouseOverImage(1)">
    <a href="image1.jpg">
        <img src="image1.jpg" width=100 height=100>
        <span>
            <img src="image1.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="example image" />
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
```

And then add the javascript handling. If you use jQuery it would become more easier:

```
<script>
    function onMouseOverImage(imageNumber) {
        var text = getTextForImage(imageNumber);
        var element = document.getElementById("IdOfTextDisplay");
        element.innerHtml = text;
    }
</script>
```

or with jQuery:

```
<script>
    function onMouseOverImage(imageNumber) {
        $("IdOfTextDisplay").text(getTextForImage(imageNumber));
    }
</script>
```

No guarantee on syntax. ;)

EDIT: You may have to place the event registration (onmouseover="onMouseOverImage(1)") into your link (a) or img. I'm not sure right now about that.